# NSMutableArray move last object to first position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a UITableview that has 8 rows corresponding to my NSMutableArray with 8 elements.

I want to move index 7 in the array to index 0, pushing down the previous index 0 to index 1. The previous index 6 would now be in index 7 position.

When I use `- insertObject:atIndex:` my tableView crashes saying that the number or array items is now 9 instead of 8.

I have tried to create a temp array to hold the elements of the mutable array but I want a smooth transition of the cells moving downward instead of just reloading. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code in a `beginUpdates-endUpdates` block. For example

```
  [tableView beginUpdates];
  id object = [mutableArray lastObject];
  [mutableArray removeLastObject];
  [mutableArray insertObject:object atIndex:0];
  [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:mutableArray.count]
                    toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0]];
  [tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting object in your array so it will increase your array count

```
id object = [self.array objectAtIndex:index];
[self.array removeObjectAtIndex:index];
[self.array insertObject:object atIndex:newIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
id object =[self.array lastObject];
[self.array removeLastObject];
[self.array insertObject:object atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Could you provide a little explanation for your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: it copy the last object from array to variable name "object". Then from the array it will remove last object . and then variable "object" added to the index 0 in the array. so finally last object added to the position 0 and all other object moved down by 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your `dataSource` and update your `TableView` to be consistent:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[dataSource count]-1 inSection:0];
[tabelView beginUpdates];
[dataSource insertObject:[dataSource lastObject] atIndex:0];
[dataSource removeLastObject];
[t moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]];
[tabelView endUpdates];
```